# Insert into two tables simultaneously primary key and foreign key using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables 'invoice' with 'invoice_no' as primary key and 'invoice_details' with 'invoice_no' as foreign key. I want to insert data into both tables simultaneously using Laravel.
The problem is when I submit the form, data is being stored into invoice table but not into invoice_details giving me integrity constraint violation error that foreign key is null.

Here is the controller code:

```
public function insertInv(Request $request){
        
        //insert into invice
        $customer_name = $request->input('customer_name');
        $c_email = $request->input('c_email');
        $c_phone = $request->input('c_phone');
        $billing_address = $request->input('billing_address');
        $term = $request->input('term');
        $order_date = $request->input('order_date');
        $due_date = $request->input('due_date');
        $discount = $request->input('discount');
        $net_total = $request->input('net_total');
        $paid = $request->input('paid');
        $due = $request->input('due');
        $payment_type = $request->input('payment_type');
        $invoice_msg = $request->input('invoice_msg');
        

        //insert into invoice_details
        $invoice_no = $request->input('invoice_no');
        $product_name = $request->input('state');
        $inven_name = $request->input('country');
        $unit = $request->input('unit');
        $price = $request->input('price');
        $qty = $request->input('cqty');
        $sub_total = $request->input('sub_total');


        //insert into invoice
        $invo=array('customer_name'=>$customer_name,'c_email'=>$c_email,'c_phone'=>$c_phone,'billing_address'=>$billing_address,'term'=>$term,'order_date'=>$order_date,'due_date'=>$due_date,'discount'=>$discount,'net_total'=>$net_total,'paid'=>$paid,'due'=>$due,'payment_type'=>$payment_type,'invoice_msg'=>$invoice_msg );

        DB::table('invoice')->insert($invo);

        
        //insert into invoice_details
        $invo_det=array('invoice_no'=>$invoice_no,'product_name'=>$product_name,'inven_name'=>$inven_name,'unit'=>$unit,'price'=>$price,'qty'=>$qty,'sub_total'=>$sub_total);

        DB::table('invoice_details')->insert($invo_det);
        
     
        return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: it's better to use laravel relationships https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [insertGetId](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts) method:

```
$invoiceId= DB::table('invoice')->insertGetId($invo);     
$invo_det=array('invoice_no'=>$invoiceId,'product_name'=>$product_name,'inven_name'=>$inven_name,'unit'=>$unit,'price'=>$price,'qty'=>$qty,'sub_total'=>$sub_total);

    DB::table('invoice_details')->insert($invo_det);
```

i also recommend that you do this inside a [transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#database-transactions)